Styling BarLegend frame/edge/axis/ticks
Consider the following plot.

Produced with this code:
ArrayPlot[{{1, 0, 0, 0.3}, {1, 1, 0, 0.3}, {1, 0, 1, 0.7}}, PlotLegends ->BarLegend[Automatic, LabelStyle -> Directive[Medium, Black]], ImageSize -> 500, FrameStyle -> Black]

I would like to be able to make the BarLegend edging/frame/axis and ticks a darker colour as the white part of the legend nearly blends into the white background of the plot. Analogous to the way FrameStyle has been used for the plot itself.
I was hoping for something like AxesStyle or FrameStyle to be an option for BarLegend. But these are not options.
I assume this functionality is there to do what I would like to achieve, but cannot find how to do it. I assume I am missing something obvious, but any help would be greatly received.

A couple of options:
ArrayPlot[{{1, 0, 0, 0.3}, {1, 1, 0, 0.3}, {1, 0, 1, 0.7}},
 PlotLegends ->
  BarLegend[Automatic,
   LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 12},
   LegendFunction -> "Panel",
   Method -> {TicksStyle -> {Black, AbsoluteThickness[1]}}],
 ImageSize -> 500,
 FrameStyle -> Black]



Thanks. The following nearly does it, but missed the left, top and bottom of the edging around the bar legend. Method -> {TicksStyle -> {Black, AbsoluteThickness[1]},
FrameStyle -> {Black, AbsoluteThickness[1]}}]}
